# How do I compose this sql query in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have got an sql query that pulls out all sorts of information. Part of it is the following

```
  select gsm.mobile_no, emp.employee_id, d.department_id
  from data gsm, employees emp, department d
  where gsm.code = e.code
  and d.id = e.id
```

Now there's a column called roaming in another table called "call" . Here's the problem. There's information from the call table for **only some** of the mobile numbers so when I join gsm.code = call.id like below

```
  select gsm.mobile_no, emp.employee_id, d.department_id, roaming.name 
  from data gsm, employees emp, department d, call roaming
  where gsm.code = e.code
  and d.id = e.i
  and roaming.id = gsm.code
```

Then I lose information about employees and departments  since only the records that satisfy the condition roaming.id = gsm.code are retrieved so I lose info about departments, employees and all other mobile numbers. I want to retrieve all records from all tables including roaming.id for the mobile numbers where applicable and if there's no data available for some of the mobile numbers then display null but I want all of the records displayed. 
How could I do that?

Comment: how about changing the query to use [outer joins](http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_oracle_left_outer_join.htm)?

Comment: using a `LEFT JOIN` at the place of `INNER JOIN` and join conditions in `ON` at the place of the conditions in `WHERE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your time has come to move to the world of modern `join` syntax.  Put your `join` conditions in the `on` clause and remember the simple rule:  Never use a comma in the `from` clause.

What you need is a `left outer join`.  You can't really do that in the `where` clause.  Well, you can in Oracle, but it is not pretty and not as good as a real `left outer join`.

```
select gsm.mobile_no, emp.employee_id, d.department_id, roaming.name 
from employes left outer join
     data gsm
     on gsm.code = e.code left join
     department d
     on d.id = e.i left outer join
     call roaming
     on  roaming.id = gsm.code;
```

Although you can mix inner and outer joins, you want to keep all employees.  So start with that table and make all the joins `left outer join`.

Comment: Oh that would be a lot of rewriting since I have got loads of other inner joins in the form of where clause. Is it possible to use left outer join in a where clause just once?